# How to fix Python putting wrong value in MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to add the value to MySQL database using Python, but for some reason it puts different number than it should.

I tried many syntax and look for help online but no luck. I am using mysql.connector, Python 3.7.

I expected the output:

```
(12, 'TEST_JOB', 'SOME_TESTING', '20/7/2019')
```

but I got:

```
(12, 'TEST_JOB', 'SOME_TESTING', '0.001415127715205547')
```

Code:

```py
TODAY = date.today().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
def add_row_to_database(row = ''):
    if row == '': return "This is not gonna happened, wrong row"
    query = f"INSERT INTO my_table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (%s, %s, {TODAY})"
    cursor.execute(query, row)
    connection.commit()
add_row_to_database('TEST_JOB', 'SOME_TESTING')
```

Comment: Check if the data type of the last field is `date` and not something else

Comment: when i use print(TODAY) it prints 20/7/2019, i am almost sure it's about syntax of query

Comment: The date string is being interpreted as a division operation.  TODAY should be part of `row`, so the values clause is `VALUES (%s, %s, %s)`.

Comment: Ok but when i try syntax:
query = f"INSERT INTO my_table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (%s, %s, '12345')"
it does work

Comment: you should use `' '`  like in `'12345'` - `'{TODAY}'`. If you don't use `' '` then date `20/7/2019` is treated by SQL as division which gives result `0.001415127715205547`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from @furas solved the problem.

> you should use `' '`  like in `'12345'` - `'{TODAY}'`. If you don't use `' '` then date `20/7/2019` is treated by SQL as division which gives result `0.001415127715205547`